# AngularJS function fails update with json string value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, d3.js

I have dropdown menu created with `ng-repeat`, however if the json is string, my function will fail. But it works just fine if its integer.

[HERE IS EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/qezepi/edit?html,js,output)

As you guys can see, chart will upload just fine with year select dropdown.
I believe because data is integer  for ex.`"year": 2011`

I also have quarter dropdown. with `"quarter": "1"`, this will fail to update, however if I have `"quarter": 2` which works just fine.

```
<select class="YearSelector" ng-model="selectedyear" ng-change="sampleDropDown()">
      <option ng-repeat="year in filterOptions.stores |  unique: 'year'">
        {{ year.year }}</option>
    </select>
    Quarter:
    <select class="QuarterSelector" ng-model="$parent.quarter" ng-change="sampleDropDown()">
      <option ng-repeat="quarter in filterOptions.stores | unique: 'quarter'">
        {{ quarter.quarter }}</option>
    </select>
```

My function:

```
 $scope.sampleDropDown = function(){
myChart.data = getData(data, $scope.selectedyear, $scope.quarter);
myChart.draw(500);
```

}

Comment: works fine when you cast comparison values to number in your filtering

Comment: @charlietfl did quite understand what you meant :/ if its okay can you post so I can test and see what you changed and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @charlietfl I added what I think you're suggesting is the best choice for Mahmut. Can you confirm? Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your HTML markup causes option values end up with a leading carriage return. You can see it if you add a console.log like the following:

```
function getData(data, year, quarter) {
  console.log("year value '" + year + "'") ;
```

In the console you'll see:

```
"year value '
        2011'"
```

If you change your HTML option markup to be all on one line I think you'll be good-to-go, e.g. for the quarter:

```
<option ng-repeat ...>{{ quarter.quarter }}</option>
```

Also, you could use [Angular's ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of the option+ng-repeat combination.

Answer (score 1):

I think @charlietfl means, you should just convert your strings to numbers.

```
 $scope.sampleDropDown = function(){
    myChart.data = getData(data,  parseInt($scope.selectedyear), parseInt($scope.quarter));
    myChart.draw(500);
  }
```

IMO, the error seems more to do with myChart.draw than Angular.

Comment: This kinda works, becuase it looks like you have to select from down quarter first then years. Otherwise if you select year first it fails to load chart. Also, if I decide to filter with different data such as like countries and such i don't think this will work :/ Thank you though

Comment: yeah, lets see what other answers come in.. I think you could convetr in getdata or in the filter... or maybe use lodash to clean up the integer column data,.. what type of solution are you looking for?

Comment: okay, in my real data, I have 5 dropdown selection, 2(integer) 3(string). I think in the filter will be much clean. Never heard lodash, but looks like I can use in my ng-repeat instead of the function that I defined for my dropdown.

Comment: ok. I will come back in a couple hours and see if anything has changed. if not, i will see if I can come up with something more elegant.